# How can I pass the spec option to cypress using a bash variable?

Tags: bash, cypress, command-line-interface

I am setting up a bash script to start a docker container, start my app and then run my cypress tests. I am trying to add an argument to the bash script so that users can either run  all specs, or pass in a specific spec to run. The line to run the script looks like this:
`src/clientapp/cypress/support/run_cypress_tests.bat '--spec \"cypress\e2e\customers.cy.ts\"'`
where `run_cypress_tests.bat` is the batch file with the script and `'--spec \"cypress\e2e\customers.cy.ts\"'` is the argument passed to the script.
In the script, it uses the variable with the `cypress run` command:

```
start /wait npx cypress run --browser chrome %1
```

But cypress is throwing an error, `unknown option --spec "cypress\e2e\customers.cy.ts"`.
I worked on it to make sure it passed in the double quotes but it doesn't work!
I also tried with single quotes and without quotes around the path to the spec, it did not work.

Comment: Sure, I thought maybe the start command opens a powershell window but I think it's just a regular command prompt.

Comment: I assume `run_cypress_tests.bat` is a windows command file. I'd recommend to convert it to bash format where it's easier to handle quoting.

Comment: What do I need to convert?

Comment: Let's stay with you rcurrent approach, can you try `src/clientapp/cypress/support/run_cypress_tests.bat --spec 'cypress\e2e\customers.cy.ts'` and `start /wait npx cypress run --browser chrome %1 %2`

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Philippe for your comment which resolved my issue:
I updated the script to read it as 2 arguments: `start /wait npx cypress run --browser chrome %1 %2` and ran `src/clientapp/cypress/support/run_cypress_tests.bat --spec 'cypress\e2e\customers.cy.ts'`.